# console.log to be executed from a html file ANGULAR

Tags: javascript, html, angular

A bit crazy one...

Is there any way to have a console.log() to run from a html file like below in angular:

```
<option (click)="consol.log('printed')">Test</option>
```

not any specific requirement, just wanted to know

Answer (score 1):

Yes

```
<button onclick="console.log('printed')">print</button>
```